# Formatar print de um objeto

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, print

Time, preciso formatar o print da seguinte classe:

```
class Tupla:

def __init__(self, keys, palavras):
    self.keys = list(keys)
    self.palavras = list(palavras)
    self.op = dict(zip(self.keys, self.palavras))

def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.op[key]

def __repr__(self):
    return f'Tabela Completa: {self.op}'

def get_tupla(self, key):
    return f'Palavra: {self.op[key]}'
```

Acredito q seja no método:

```
    def __repr__(self):
    return f'Tabela Completa: {self.op}'
```

Queria que o resultado fosse (Para cada um dos elementos do dicionário):

```
Key:   | Palavra:
```

Segunda fase da pergunta:

```
    def get_pagina(self, num):
    to_print = "Key:\t| Palavra:\n"
    for item in self.paginas[num]:
        to_print += str(item) + "\t\t  " + str(self.paginas[item]) + "\n"
    return to_print
```

Onde:

```
    aux = list(zip(keys, palavras))
    self.paginas = list()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para alterar o que será exibido quando você passar o objeto para o método print(), você deve sobrescrever o método `__str__()` do objeto e retornar uma string.

```
class Tupla:

    def __init__(self, keys, palavras):
        self.keys = list(keys)
        self.palavras = list(palavras)
        self.op = dict(zip(self.keys, self.palavras))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.op[key]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Tabela Completa: {self.op}'

    def get_tupla(self, key):
        return f'Palavra: {self.op[key]}'

    def __str__(self):
        to_print = "Key:\t| Palavra:\n"
        for item in self.op:
            to_print += str(item) + "\t\t  " + str(self.op.get(item)) + "\n"
        return to_print


t = Tupla(keys=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), palavras=("um", "dois", "tres", "quatro", "cinco"))
print(t)
```

Comment: Renan,era exatamente isso, obg ! Mas tentando reproduzir o teu exemplo, bati em outro erro mas dessa vez em uma segunda classe, tem como dar uma olhada ? Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Desculpa a leiguice, comecei agora a programar...

Comment: Que erro está acontecendo e o que você esperava que estivesse acontecendo?

Comment: Bom eu queria printar uma página específica: Página: {num} | Palavras: {}

Comment: Quando você faz self.paginas[num] te retorna uma lista de palavras naquela página? Se sim, comece a string com to_print = "Key: {}\t | Palavra: ".format(num) e dentro do for você vai acrescentando as palavras to_print += str(item) + " "